# When is the index of array compared with -1

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have seen multiple codes where index of arrays are compared to -1, like

```
if (index === -1)
```

What does this exactly do?

I believe we can't store values in negative index, at least as array element. (I know, As a property of array, we can indeed do that). But then when will the above condition return true or false?

Comment: As addition to @Joseph the Dreamer answer: for "beauty" comparison sometimes used bitwise operator '~'. It equals expression -(n+1). So you can write it like `if ( ~str.indexOf(...) ) { console.log('Found!') }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider below code

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var index = fruits.indexOf("Apple"); 

if(index != -1) {
alert ("Apple found at " + index)
} else {
alert ("Apple not in exists")
}
```

array indexof returns index number(0 or 1 or 2) of the value if the value exists but returns -1 if the value does not exists.

thanks!

Comment: Think you have that comparison backward. In any case, Joseph already covered this ground several minutes ago.

Comment: Did not see his reply when I started typing my answer and it took some time when i was typing my answer and Joseph was little faster than me.

Comment: @Shahid  index value in your code will be 2. Why should `Apple found at + index` be shown when `index=== -1` be true

Comment: @Suarabh - I have corrected the if condition thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 12):

This is usually used with an [array's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) or [string's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) `indexOf` operation. `indexOf` returns a `-1` when the value is not in the array. Otherwise, it returns a zero-based index of the first match it finds.

The condition you have above probably checks if an item *does not* exist in the array.

Comment: And yes, before anyone asks, it is *reliably* -1, not just a negative number, for `Array#indexOf` and `String#indexOf` (and `Array#findIndex`). Naturally YMMV with other functions, check their specification.

Comment: ... and -1 was specifically chosen because, as OP mentions, "we can't store values in negative index", so it's suited for the "not found" value.